# Microsoft SQL Server Error: "Incorrect syntax near keyword Select"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dbo

Unsure what syntax the error  is referring to at this statement  :-

```
Use MyDatabase
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
    AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Although that is standard SQL, this is not supported by SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didnt realize that standard SQL wasnt supported by SQL Server. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dbo` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  The syntax error is that this syntax is not supported.

The equivalent syntax in SQL Server is:

```
SELECT *
INTO TestTable
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below. The one you are using is Oracle syntax.

```
Use MyDatabase
Go

SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM dbo.MyTable
GO
```

Comment: Not just Oracle. CTAS (Create Table As SELECT...) is supported by most RDBMs, including Azure. Not sure why it hasn't been introduced into SQL Server yet. Maybe vNext.